# Php form will not submit correctly with jQuery validation added

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

**UPDATE**

Trying new code from OhGodWhy's comments. When I click submit with this code, nothing happens:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#jobapp").validate({
                 debug: false,
           rules: {
            email: {
             required: true,
             email: true
            }
           },
           messages: {
            email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
           },
           submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax('../scripts/process-application.php', new FormData($("#jobapp")[0]), function(data) {
             processData: false;
             $('#confirm').html(data);
             $('#job-application').hide();
            });
           }
          });
         });
        </script>
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm trying to submit a form that includes 3 text fields, a rich text field, and a file upload.  I have successfully used the jQuery validation on another form and it works perfectly.  However, when I update the code for this form, it won't submit the rich text data or file that is uploaded.  The information put into the name, email and phone fields makes it to the database, but the last two (rich text and file selection) do not, and the corresponding email is not sent.  Upon submission of the form, I see the message I have written to display if everything is not OK.

I am very new to PHP and not sure how to troubleshoot this. My understanding of jQuery is also limited.  I tried following [the steps here](http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/qt/php_error_reporting.htm) but don't see anything on the screen other than the message I typed up. I do not see any error messages in the console when I look at the developer tools in FF or Chrome. If I remove the jQuery validation script everything works perfectly.

Can anyone help me please? Here is the `js` on my form page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jobapp").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules: {
    email: {
     required: true,
     email: true
    }
   },
   messages: {
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
   },
   submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.post('../scripts/process-application.php', $("#jobapp").serialize(), function(data) {
     $('#confirm').html(data);
     $('#job-application').hide();
    });
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

This is the HTML for the form:

```
<div id="job-application">
<p><span>Position:</span> <?php echo $jobtitle;?></p>
<p><span>Job ID:</span> <?php echo $jobid;?></p>
<p class="req">All Fields are Required</p>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="jobapp" id="jobapp">
<input name="jobtitle" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $jobtitle;?>" />
<input name="jobid" type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $jobid;?>" />   
 <label>Full Name</label><input name="name" type="text" id="name"/>
 <label>Email</label><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="35" />
 <label>Phone</label><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="35" />
 <label>Cover Letter</label><textarea name="coverletter" id="coverletter"></textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'coverletter' );
        </script><br />
 <label>Upload Resume:</label><input type="file" name="resume"  />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
<input name="clear" type="reset" value="Clear Form"  class="button"/>
</form>
</div>
<div id="confirm"></div>
```

And this is the php file to process the application:

```
<link href="../assets/lcoastyles.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<?php require_once('lcoa.php'); ?>
<?php 
 //This is the directory where resumes will be saved 
 $target = "../careers/resumes/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['resume']['name']); 
 $resume=($_FILES['resume']['name']);
 //Writes the information to the database 
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO applicants (id, name, email, phone, jobid, jobtitle, coverletter, resume) VALUES ('','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['phone']."','".$_POST['jobid']."','".$_POST['jobtitle']."','".$_POST['coverletter']."','".$resume."')";
        mysql_select_db($database_lcoa, $lcoa);
        $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $lcoa) or die(mysql_error());
//Writes the resume to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Sends Email
$sendto   = "email@email.com";
$name  = nl2br($_POST['name']);
$email  = nl2br($_POST['email']);
$phone  = nl2br($_POST['phone']);
$jobid = nl2br($_POST['jobid']);
$jobtitle = nl2br($_POST['jobtitle']);
$cover = nl2br($_POST['coverletter']);
$subject  = "Submitted Job Application";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Job Application Submitted</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Applied for:</strong> ".$jobtitle."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<a href='http://lcoawebservices.com/careers/resumes/".$resume."'>Download Resume</a>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "false";
}


 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "<p>Thank you for submitting your application.  Resumes submitted will be reviewed to determine qualifications that match our hiring needs.<br /><br />  If you are selected you will be contacted by a member of our recruiting team.</p><br /><br /><a href='../careers/job-postings.php'>Return to current opportunities</a>"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file. Please try again.<br /><br />If you continue to experience errors, please email lcoaweb@lecreuset.com."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

I know this is a lot of code, not sure what a better way to show you would be.  Thank you for your attention to this.

Comment: if you downvote my question, can you please let me know why so i can do better next time? thank you.

Comment: Open up a console in your web browser (F12 in Chrome and IE) and then try to submit again, see if you get any error information in the console. An error is probably being returned to you via the console.

Comment: replace `$("#jobapp").serialize()` with `new FormData($("#jobapp")[0]);`. In HTML5 you can send files to the server with ajax, but you can't do it using serialize. I am also unsure if this works in IE < 10

Comment: @BOMEz, I'm not getting any error messages in the console. I will update my question to let others know too.

Comment: There will be no error message, jQuery just will not serialize the File Data, meaning that data will be sent, so it will be successful; however, no file will be included. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I just tried that but I got an error in the console: Illegal Invocation

Comment: Change `$.post()` to `$.ajax()` and add `processData: false` to your ajax request.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy no dice, Uncaught Typeerror: Object is not a function

Comment: Version of jQuery? If it's below 1.9, then upgrade. Also, update the post with the new `$.ajax()` you built.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy done. Using jQuery 1.10.1

Comment: [No no, THIS is how the .ajax() needs to be built.](http://jsfiddle.net/rBcgU/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thank you! Geez, I have a lot to learn. I updated based on your fiddle.  Now the form will submit but gives the error message I saw originally, and nothing is going to the database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32187/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-surfbird0713)